# how the performance of the code gets increased while defining the method in .cpp file rather than defining it in the .h file in c++?

Tags: c++

I read in a book that defining the method (of a class) in a `.cpp` file rather than defining it inside the class in declaration (`.h` file) will reduce memory usage and speed up compilation time.

> Moving member function definitions from class definition to a separate .cpp file generally speeds up compilation times and reduces memory usage

I tried to implement it in C++ code, but the execution time varies at every time, so I am unable to examine it clearly. Can anyone help me to understand this concept?

Comment: The book says **compilation** time, not execution time.

Comment: If your function is used in multiple cpps, the execution time can be better if you define that function in *.h because the compiler will have chance to inline it.

Comment: thanks for the reply ..but how can we identify the compilation time separately in code ? can u give me some suggestion?

Comment: Can you post the exact quote from the book, because the current quote has some typing errors that might change the meaning? Does the book say "will improve performance and speed up compilation time" or something else?

Comment: Moving member function definitions from class definition to a separate .cpp file generally speeds up compilation times and reduces memory usage

Answer (score 2):

As you said, defining the method in the `.cpp` instead of in the `.h` improves performance and speedup of *compilation time*.

Note that both attributes (performance and speedup) are applied to *compilation time*. It does not improve performance at runtime.

About why it improves performance of compilation time, it is because the method is only parsed and compiled in just the `.cpp` where it is defined, while if it is defined in the `.h` it is parsed and compiled in all the `.cpp`s where the header is included, thus reducing the total compilation speed [1]

---

[1] In this blog post, it is explained further and with more detail:
http://gameangst.com/?p=224

Comment: *"As you said, defining the method in the .cpp instead of in the .h improves performance and speedup of compilation time."* - this is not true at all. *"Actually, at runtime it can reduce performance, since the method will not be inlined anymore."* - function definition location has no impact on inlining while inlining may or may not result in faster or slower code. This answer is mostly misleading.

Comment: @VTT Why is not true? It reduces dependencies, reduces includes and processing requirements for each .cpp where this method is not defined. So, maybe not always, but 90% of the time moving the method (and all its dependencies) to the .cpp will improve compilation  time. Function definition in .h allows for inlining (not always, but it is allowed) while if its defined in .cpp it is disallowed to inline (outside that .cpp, how would the compiler include the code if it does not see the implementation details?)

Comment: It may seem obvious, but if you keep definitions in header files then you won't need corresponding .cpp at all. And reducing amount of translation units (ideally to just one) is the core idea of all the high-performance build systems (so-called jumbo / unity / aho builds). You may argue that moving just one function to .cpp if that .cpp file exists anyway may improve build performance a bit, but just one function is insignificant for overall build performance.

Comment: As for you second question see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079747/how-the-performance-of-the-code-gets-increased-while-defining-the-method-in-cpp/58079837?noredirect=1#comment102554398_58079967)

Answer (score 2):

Location of function definition has no impact on code performance as long as it is compiled into a single binary. Note that functions may be inlined even if they are not defined in header files and may be not inlined even if they are defined in header files.

Depending on project organization putting definitions into header files rather than in .cpp files may greatly improve build times or make them worse. For fastest builds putting definitions into header files is mandatory.

Comment: How can a function be inlined even if it is not defined in a header file?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler That's what various link-time code optimizations are performing. For example gcc's LTO: *When the object files are linked together, all the function bodies are read from these ELF sections and instantiated as if they had been part of the same translation unit.*

Comment: But link-time optimization isn't what is typically meant with "inlining", is it?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler Inlining typically means any inline expansion whether the optimisation was made by the compiler or the linker.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler By "inlining" I mean a situation when function body is embedded at the point of function invocation rather than a proper call.

Comment: @VTT Okay, according to Wikipedia your are right. My usage of the word "inlining" was too restricted.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the method definition into a .cpp file, it gets compiled once and every call of this method in other .cpp files will get linked to this single compiled version of the method.

If you put the method definition into header file, it's as if you copy pasted it into every .cpp file the header is included in, and it has to be compiled in each .cpp file compilation separately, which of course takes more time than compiling it once.

Comment: u saying that in the scenario of having common header file which is used in multiple cpp files ..am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

If a function is defined *inline* in a class, the compiler is allowed to put it inline instead of calling it (basically copies the code into the location of the call). That can improve *run-time* performance.

But also, inline functions will cause the compilation of each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) where the header file containing the class to recompile that exact function definition which could make the build-process longer.

Comment: but the function will not occupy space in the class declaration..will it? and also the function definition will be common for all the objects , so i think  memory will be created separately  for data members not for methods..

Comment: @Priya No member functions will be part of the "class" or be counted by `sizeof` for the class. But an inline definition, if it's inlined by the compiler, will be stored in multiple places, as each inlining duplicates the code of the function.

Answer (score 0):

> ... will improves performance and speedup compilation time

The book is wrong on the first part. It does not improve (runtime) performance of a program to define functions externally. In fact, if it wasn't for link time optimisation, it would have the opposite effect due to potentially preventing inline expansion.

The latter claim is not as dubious, although truth is not that simple. Having multiple translation units generally slows down the compilation time of the project *from scratch*. However, being able to compile only the translation units that have been changed can significantly reduce the compilation time of incremental changes when those translation units are small.